# iPhone UIButton Multiple Clicks Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have an UIButton, which logs the content that is present in a couple of UITextField's.But when I click on this UIButton thrice, the simulator hangs and the debugger is opened. Can someone tell me why is this happening. It happens only when there is content in UITextFields.

Comment: Can you post a code snippet? It is hard to know what is wrong just on that description.

Comment: Do you have a backtrace you can provide, and/or the code related to the button where the crash is taking place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your code it's hard to diagnose, but it sorta sounds like you are releasing something you shouldn't be. The first two times the object is still valid, but the third time might make an object's retain count zero, and therefore prematurely deallocate it. Check the IBAction method for your UIButton and make sure you aren't releasing things that you haven't explicitly allocated.